OAuth2/OIDC : how to identify client application
TL/DR: my questions are at the end of this message but basically I'm asking what are the standards to identify a client application from a web-service perspective?
More context: we are working at my company on re-building our authentication and authorization mechanisms for a year now.
As many companies we have multiple web-services, talking between them (M2M), that can be called from our internal organization or from outside (by external companies). For increasing security level and inter-operability we have moved to OAuth2/OIDC protocols (based on Keycloak as Authorization Server), and it's working well.
The problem we are facing now is, in order to notify our customers of breaking changes, depreciations, warnings, etc (and for increasing audit capability), we need to identify the customer application, not the user, calling each of our web-services (then attach an email - or whatever - to this identity, but this is out of my question's scope). We can't rely on the user account since the user account can legitimately be used from another customer application. We can't rely on low-level protocols (e.g using the source IP to identify them is impossible because of NAT and many reasons). We assume that we can't neither rely on the Access Token or ID Token (e.g the azp claim) since these tokens could legitimately be used downstream by other processes (who are not the parties who have requested a token) (and since the specification of the azp claim is ambiguous and depends on implementation - e.g Google does not respect the standard if I'm correct).
So my questions are:

Could you confirm the OAuth2 and OIDC protocols are not designed to handle this use-case (or am I missing something?)?
Therefore should we implement some custom logic (e.g an additional information, owned by the caller, signed by some authority, to pass in some HTTP header for each request to our web-services, something like that) or is there some well-known standards for that?
Another option could be to rely on API Keys but it makes us uncomfortable because we would lose OAuth2/OIDC and their inter-operability benefits, standards, etc?

Thanks a lot for your expertise!
What we tried: as described above, we have evaluated multiple approaches and identify pros/cons of some of them, but we haven't been able to identify a standard and universal way to perform what we want (identifying a client application, not a user, without losing standards benefits).

After re-thinking about it (writing helps...) I realize another option is to assume that in a M2M context (with Client Credentials flow),  the client applications do not "re-use" downstream the Access Token they have received, and use a token issued with their own Client. Then if this asumption is correct we can rely on the azp claim (after customizing the Authorization Server in order to make it appear in the Access Token - in addition of the ID Token) to safely identify the client application. It looks better than implementing some custom crappy logic on top of OAuth2/OIDC.

azp is used in oidc id token. In a m2m scenario using client credentials, there shouldn't be an id token. You can use the aud claim that's one of the standard claims in a jwt. It's specified who the access token was intended for.

aud is generally intended to specify the resource server, but I'm not sure what that part of your setup is. You could also use the jti parameter that you can map to the client. It's a unique identifier per token

Thanks for answer but not sure to follow. From what is described in specification (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.3), aud is intended to identify a recipient (so the Resource Server(s)), but I want is to identify a Client. Regarding jti (that I just discover), it looks to be designed to avoid replay attacks, so if I understand well what you are proposing is a workaround (using this clay to store an arbitrary value representing the Client), am I right?

The authz server is adding the aud claim. It should know that for client C, it can use the token at aud B or a list of audiences. So, you have that mapping between something in the token, aud, and the client. However, you may have the same resource servers accessible via multiple different clients which wouldn't make this a unique mapping.

The jti is just a unique identifier tied to a specific token. If you have a client that generates tons of similar tokens and one of them gets compromised. It's much easier for the authz server to 'blacklist' the token containing a specific jti than without.  My idea was storing a map of ( jti , client id ). When you get a token you want to identify the client for, grab the jti from the token and look it up in that map to get the client id. In the end, it might just be easier to add a custom claim in Keycloak. Just add one and make sure the token is signed.

I think I mistakenly thought you were asking for how to check which client an access_token belongs to after reading your first comment.  But, since you're using client credentials grant type and you must authn the client, why don't you capture the client_id's that are coming in in the token requests, i.e., the request from the client to retrieve an access_token at the authz server's /token endpoint.  https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#autoid-50:~:text=The%20client%20MUST%20authenticate%20with%20the%20authorization%20server

Yes this is my question. We don't do that because we sometimes use the upstream token (received by service A) in downstream services (in service B called by service A for example) (without Token Exchange mechanisms as pointed by @Gary below). So in this situation we cannot rely on client_id field in toke. But as you both pointed re-using tokens downstream is a bad practice hère, if we use new tokens (or exchange) then we'll not have this issue anymore.

IDENTIFYING CLIENTS
In an M2M setup you use the client credentials grant and the authorization server will issue a claim like client_id in the access token. The exact identifier may depend on the authorization server.
This allows you to distinguish callers and then look up their particular permissions as part of your API logic. This is common in B2B deployments where multiple business partners are each registered as a distinct client and the access token enables you to tell them apart.
Your token issuance logic could also potentially issue custom claims to the access token, eg a department_id or partner_id.
ACCESS TOKEN SCOPE
Your concerns about where an access token can be used should be managed by issuing scopes and an audience claim. Each API should validate that an access token meets its own expected values for these fields.
Scopes are often areas of the business. Eg an access token with a scope of retail/sales would not be usable against an API that requires a scope of commercial/sales. The audience can represent a single API or a logical set of APIs.
This mechanism allows access tokens to safely flow between APIs when you want them to, or prevent that when you do not.
USER BASED FLOWS
In some cases (eg microservice setups) an app gets a user level access token and calls your API 1, which then calls your API 2, which also needs to work with the user identity.
In such cases the token received by API 2 should maintain the user identity in the access token and you should avoid getting a new access token for API 2 using the client credentials grant.
If API 1 trusts API 2 it might simply forward the original access token. Or API 1 could use the token exchange standard from RFC 8693 to get a new access token with updated (eg reduced) scopes and audience.
SUMMARY

Use the client credentials grant for backend clients that originate API calls
Consider token exchange as an additional grant when your own APIs call each other


There's no user ID because there's no user in the client credentials flow nor in OP's M2M scenario.

client id doesn't have to be in the access_token. If OP has that assurance and the token is signed, then this should be fine.
Downstream shouldn't reuse the tokens. Tokens represent authorization given to a particular client to access something. If you have multiple different clients, you're increasing your attack vector by widening the usage of a token and making it harder to revoke the token or credentials as all of those clients will be affected

I updated my answer. Since the question describes a microservices setup I wanted to get across some choices OAuth gives you to safely scale the use of access tokens across multiple APIs.

authorization server will issue a claim like client_id in the access token  While most providers do include this in the token, this is not necessarily true. So, I think that should be made explicit. I think your custom claims is a good alternative if they don't get the client_id by default . I also suggested to keep track of which clients come in when the client must authn with the authz server in order to retrieve a token

Thanks both for your responses. As Gary highlights I think our design issue is mainly due to we propagate tokens downstream (without re-issuing / exchanging) which is considered as a bad practice if I understand well (it reduces security and audit capability). I think the Token Exchange protocol (RFC 8693, I guess 6893 is a typo) is the right answer for our use-cases (and it's supported - as technical preview - in Keycloak so it's fine). Thanks both!
